# Adding two table columns for sorting

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sorting, associations

I am building a task management application using Ruby on Rails (3.0). I have projects and tasks. Tasks belong_to projects and projects has_many tasks.

My task table has columns for position, project_position and priority. The position column gets updated when a sortable list is moved around via AJAX. The project_position column gets updated when the projects get sorted via a sortable list and AJAX. I want the priority column to be the SUM of position and project_position so that I can :order => "priority".

Any ideas?

UPDATE:

Not sure if the following code is getting in the way:

**projects_controller.rb**

```
  def sort
    params[:projects].each_with_index do |id, index|
      Project.update_all(['position=?', index+1], ['id=?', id])
    end
    render :nothing => true
  end
```

**tasks_controller.rb**

```
  def sort
    params[:tasks].each_with_index do |id, index|
      Task.update_all(['position=?', index+1], ['id=?', id])
    end
    render :nothing => true
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do this via a `before_save` callback.

```
class Task < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_save :set_priority

  protected

  def set_priority
    self.priority = self.project_position + self.position
  end
end
```

If you are following my other suggestion to `delegate` position from the task to the project, then you may want/need a little extra checking in here to make sure the task has been built or created with a project, because if not the delegated project_position will return `nil` and you'll get an error when you try to add it.

You'll also want to go ahead with that `after_save` callback on Project, in order to have all tasks re-save and thus update their priority values on the db.

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  after_save :set_task_priorities

  protected

  def set_task_priorities
    self.tasks.each(&:save)
  end
end
```

Comment: Ok this is really great stuff. On both this and the other question. With all your advice in place I am getting an error `nil can't be coerced into Fixnum` and that is referring to the `self.priority = self.project_position + self.position` line. Any ideas?

Comment: My guess is that the `set_priority` method is trying to add `self.position` but self position isn't set yet so it's nil. That sound right?

Comment: Hey, sorry for delay. Yes, the nil can't be coerced message is regarding trying to add a number to nil. That's what I was referring to in the "a little extra checking" note above, and this is dependent on how you are building the task/project objects. If there is no project yet for the task to reference, then you'll get a nil back from the delegated method, and you can't mathematically add nil. A simple solution would be: self.priority = (self.project_position ? self.project_position : 0) + self.position. In this manner, you will add the project_position if it exists, or add 0 if it doesn't.

Comment: Or, self.priority = (self.project_position || 0) + self.position

Comment: Thanks for continuing to help. I tried both the lines of code that you provided and while it doesn't cause an error, all of the columns in task (position, priority, and project_position) get set as [Null].

Comment: Ignore that last comment...I had something wrong. Those lines do infact throw the same fixnum error.

Comment: Ok this seemed to eleviate the error: `self.priority = (self.project_position || 0) + (self.position || 0)`

Comment: The only problem now is that the task priority doesn't seem to update when I sort the projects around. Like the after_save isn't working. And the priority column doesn't seem to be adding together the task.position and the project.position to come up with task.priority value.

Comment: Rails defaults everything to null unless you specifically set something else in the migration. I would set up task.position with a default value of 0 (through a new migration), so that you have a value there all the time. With that, you wouldn't need the check on self.position. In the task model you'll want the code that updates priority to fire in a before_save, so that it gets set before you save it to the db, otherwise you lose it. In the project model, you want the call to update/save all the child tasks in an after_save, so that it only happens once the project is successfully saved.

Comment: @bgadoci let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2105/discussion-between-yardboy-and-bgadoci)